# How to read and fill in a database from another sheet without using Google Script?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-forms, gs-vlookup

I have created a [database](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FUpE3QBzV0TDqhtn6hM_MYgi2SPTZXwyaC1dIFMWTcY/edit?usp=sharing) that I want to use for reading and filling in data. I've created 2 sheets, *'Database'* and *'Data Input'*. So far I've only made it in a way that I can read certain data when I choose an ID from *'Database'* - all the relevant data will be shown in *'Data Input'*.

But ideally, I would want to be able to not only read, but also to input some data through *'Data input'* and that it would be assigned to a needed ID in *'Dabatase'* and saved in respective fields.

All the ID's in *'Database'* are pre-assigned even to empty fields, so in order for me to be able to input and save some data, I'd just choose a needed ID in *'Data Input'* B2 cell - let's say, 1203, and input the name and adress etc. data in B3:B11. Those data would be then shown and saved in *'Database'*. The database person under ID 1203 would then have a filled name, adress etc.

So far, I've only figured a half-way solution with only adding some extra fields (marked orange) and writing a VLOOKUP function in *'Database'* in the same fields for reading those input data out of *'Data Input'* in case their ID's match. BUT, in order to really save the data in *'Database'*, I have to manually select a field there and Ctrl+Cmd+V.

But I would like to be able to:

a) make the data be saved automatically after I input them through *'Input data'* (for that, probably some kind of trigger for saving is needed), and

b) fill or change already filled in data for all the fields in *'Database'* through *'Data Input'* and not just the orange ones.

Is it even possible to do this without using Google Script? My workload is pretty hight and learning another programming language just for creating this one table would probably be too much time for me. Therefore, I would appreciate any hints and help.

The mentioned table here was just created for this post, but it mirrors the original database in its form.

Comment: Welcome! I tried opening your spreadsheet but was denied access. Can you grant access for us to review your sample data? Thanks!

Comment: I am sorry, it should work now, please try again

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered [Google Forms](https://www.google.com/forms/about/)? Responses from a Google Form can be logged in a spreadsheet as you're describing. However, it won't be able to accomplish requirement (b) of changing existing records.

Otherwise, what you're requesting is not possible to accomplish in Google Sheets without Apps Script.

Comment: Thank you, then I'll stick to the system I have now and I'll consider learning to write Google Scripts in the future.

Answer (score 0):

> I would want to be able to not only read, but also to input some data through 'Data input'

this step is not possible unless you use a script

the best way to achieve what you want is to set up a simple Google Form and increase your database via that. then you can have a tab with those VLOOKUPs and quick-search stuff if needed

[image: 0]